# Azure Cosmos DocumentDB - return array from 1 property in sub array

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've searched around to see if anybody needed this before but couldn't find much.

I have the following json objects in Azure DocumentDB collection:

```
{
    personID: 1,
    name: "Bruce",
    surname: "Dickinson",
    items: [
        {
            itemID: 1,
            itemType: "A",
            name: 'Item 1'
        },
        {
            itemID: 2,
            itemType: "A",
            name: 'Item 2'
        },
        {
            itemID: 3,
            itemType: "B",
            name: 'Item 3'
        }
    ]

}
```

The collection has many Persons in it. personID 2, 3, 4 ......100....1000 and so on.

I would like to write a SQL query to extract an array of itemIDs for personID = 1 and items with itemType = 'A'. I want the result to look like this:

```
itemIDs: [
    1,
    2
]
```

or simply:

```
[
    1,
    2
]
```

Has anybody ever tried doing this before? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Someone with more SQL foo than me might know a way to do it with just SQL, but I would use a user-defined function (UDF) to do it.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT VALUE udf.getItemIDArray(c) FROM collection c WHERE <your clause>
```

Here's what the UDF might look like:

```
function getItemIDArray (o) {
  output = [];
  for (item in o.items) {
    output.push(item.itemID)
  }
  return output 
}
```

Comment: Mmmm interesting. Thanks for that. The output.push(item.itemID) seems to be pushing a null instead of the item.itemID. Why would that be  you think?

Comment: Hmm try putting a "var" in front of "for (var item in o.items)"

Comment: Still did not work. I am doing it in the application for the time being but would like to do it at the db level to transport less over the network.